# архивы rar не rar

Tags: zip, rar

Объясните пожалуйста, как такое возможно?

В папки архив rar, в winrar это zip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правая кнопка мыши по файлу → Переименовать → заменить "zip" в названии на что угодно, хоть на "mp3"

Comment: нет, вы наверное не поняли мой вопрос, разрешение архива написано rar, а в программе написано zip

Comment: Ну да, кто-то нажал «Переименовать» и исправил «zip» на «rar», вот и всё

Comment: Это пакет `resource adapter`а для сервера javaee. Согласно соответствующей спецификации пакуется в zip, а расширение проставляется `rar` (`R`esource adapter `AR`chive:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- В **списке файлов папки** применяется быстрый, но не настоящий алгоритм —  тип файла определяется только **расширением его имени**. Даже в списке файлов программы WinRar!

  Значит эго только *предположение, догадка* об содержании файла.

---

- Когда вы попросите WinRar информации об **индивидуальном** файле, WinRar *открывает файл и читает информацию* **прямо из него**.

  (Первые байты в начале файла идентифицируют его действительное содержание.)

Answer (score 4):

Всё довольно простою Формат архива ZIP, наименование файла .rar . WinRar так умеет.

[image]

Comment: как убрать это наименование?

Comment: переименуйте файл и всё.