# Oператор or python zipfile rarfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как правильно это реализовать?

```
archive= zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') or rarfile.RarFile(file,'r')
```

Comment: Вместо непонятного псевдокода лучше словами расскажите, что вы хотите

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы открывался либо рар либо зип архив, в зависимости от расширения архива

Comment: Если ситуация в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1126822) вас не смущает, то просто написать что-то в духе `if file.endswith('.zip')` и выполнить соответствующий код, да и всё

Answer (score 0):

Примените `try-except`:

```
try:
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file)           # 'r' не надо
except zipfile.BadZipFile:
    archive = rarfile.RarFile(file)           # 'r' не надо
```

— или — лучше:

```
try:
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file)           # 'r' не надо
except zipfile.BadZipFile:
    try:
        archive = rarfile.RarFile(file)       # 'r' не надо
    except rarfile.BadRarFile: 
        print("Ошибка - файл не является ни ZIP, ни RAR файлом")
```